# Increment count to limit number of times a user can dynamically add a form element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic, increment

I started with a jquery function and got help on it and then modified it a little more. The code I have below works.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_project" title="Add project"><i data-feather="plus-circle"></i> Add another project</a>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  const projectHTML = `<tr>
    <td>
      <select name="improvement_project[]" class="custom-select">
          <option selected>Select project</option>
        <optgroup label="Interior">
          <option>New Master/Owner's Suite</option>
          <option>Kitchen Upgrade</option>
       </select>
     </td>
  </tr>`;

  const $projects   = $("#projects");
  const $addProject = $('.add_project');
  const arrRow = () => $projects.append(projectHTML);

  $addProject.on("click", arrRow);
  ...
  });
});
```

Clicking on the "Add another project" button appends the projectHTML as another drop-down menu. What I'm trying to do is limit the number of times a user can add another drop-down menu, like 5 times. I'm already limiting on the backend, but of course it would be good to limit on the UI.

I set a max variable and counter variable:

```
var maxprojects = 5;
var counter = 1;
```

and then tried adding some code around the `$addProject.on("click", arrRow);` with something like:

```
if (counter < maxprojects) {
  $addProject.on("click", arrRow);
  counter++;
}
```

but that doesn't stop the click from adding more than 5 projects.

Please help me understand where I'm completely going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you provide all of your code?  Including where you tried to add the code that's not working? Best is if you make a sample on JSFiddle or a similar site.

Comment: your callback is not checking the counter but adds to the DOM. check the counter in your callback

Comment: @Marc That's a good point, I'll do that next time. I only put my working code and then thought I'd try to keep the post shorter by describing what I tried.

Comment: @gillyspy I knew something felt weird, but I couldn't see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is add a class to the new project rows and get length of that class before adding another

```
const projectHTML = `<tr class="project-row">....</tr>`;

const arrRow = () => {
  if($('tr.project-row').length < 5){
     $projects.append(projectHTML);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. I like this solution, no need to keep track of other counter variables like what I tried. And then since there was already a class attached to the form select, I used that. Thanks!

Comment: Can also use an else to disable the button if desired for better UX

Comment: True. I added `$('.add_project').hide();` once it reached 5 projects.